# angular 12 route loading component without registering the module

Tags: angular

Angular version and CLI

As a forewarning, we are moving the CLI npm package to "@angular/cli" with the next release,
which will only support Node 6.9 and greater. This package will be officially deprecated
shortly after.

To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.packageDeprecation=false".

```
                         _                           _  _
```

__ _  _ __    __ _  _   _ | |  __ _  _ __         ___ | |(*)

/  *`|| '_ \  / _` || | | || | / *` || '**|*****  / **|| || |

| (*| || | | || (*| || |*| || || (*| || |  |*****|| (** | || |

_*,*||*| |*| _*, | _*,*||*| _*,*||*|          _**||*||*|

|**_/
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
node: 14.17.4
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 12.1.4
@angular/common: 12.1.4
@angular/compiler: 12.1.4
@angular/core: 12.1.4
@angular/forms: 12.1.4
@angular/platform-browser: 12.1.4
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 12.1.4
@angular/router: 12.1.4
@angular/cli: 12.1.4
@angular/compiler-cli: 12.1.4

I having the following modules

- CoreModule
- LayoutModule
- ShareModule
- ViewModule

I do have a router-outlet in appcomponent which is the bootstrap component.

**LayoutModule**

I have 3 component which is declared in my LayoutModule
which are follows.

- ContentLayoutComponent
- AuthLayoutComponent
- SideNav

And in each layout a separate router-outlet (ContentLayoutComponent,AuthLayoutComponent)

No components are exported from that module outside.

```
import { NgModule, Optional, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';
//import { components} from './components'
import { ContentlayoutComponent } from '@layout/components/contentlayout/contentlayout.component';
import { AuthlayoutComponent } from '@layout/components/authlayout/authlayout.component';
import { SidenavComponent } from '@layout/components/sidenav/sidenav.component';
import { throwIfAlreadyLoaded } from '@core/guard';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    //...components,
    ContentlayoutComponent,AuthlayoutComponent,SidenavComponent
  ],
  imports:[RouterModule],
})
export class LayoutModule { 

constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() layoutmodule:LayoutModule){
  throwIfAlreadyLoaded(layoutmodule,'LayoutModule')
}

}
```

**AppModule**

If you see the below code i am not registering the LayoutModule.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CoreModule } from '@core/core.module';
import { LayoutModule } from '@layout/layout.module';
import { SharedModule } from '@shared/shared.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ViewsModule } from './views/views.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    ViewsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**AppComponent**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**AppRoutingModule**

Here i am using a component from layoutmodule . You can see it as ContentlayoutComponent. But i did not exported those component outside.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {NoauthGuard } from '@core/guard'
import {ContentlayoutComponent} from '@layout/components'

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/contactus',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
 {
    path: '',
    component: ContentlayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [NoauthGuard], // no authentication applied
    children: [
      {
        path: 'contactus',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('@modules/contact/contact.module').then(m => m.ContactModule)
      }
    ]
  },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Question**

How the AppRouteModule is able to load the component without registing the module? And also i did not export any component outside the layoutmodule.

You can access the same code from https://stackblitz.com/github/vipinbmenon/angular_template
But in stackbliz without registering the layoutmodule it won't work.

**Reference**
Other modules

**SharedModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  exports:[ReactiveFormsModule,CommonModule,RouterModule]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

**ViewModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { components } from './components';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...components],
  exports: [
    ...components
  ]
})
export class ViewsModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't import correctly you need to import the module correctly to use. You need import LayoutModule in AppModule.

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CoreModule } from '@core/core.module';
import { LayoutModule } from '@layout/layout.module';
import { SharedModule } from '@shared/shared.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ViewsModule } from './views/views.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    ViewsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    LayoutModule // Add Layout Module**
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: But without importing it is working. This is my question. How it is working?